# How to set Jupyter notebook output back to output cells?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How do I set a Jupyter notebook's output back to the output cells after sending its output to a file?

Sending its output to a file:

```
sys.stdout = open(filename, 'w')
print "stuff"
```

Sending its output back to the output cells:

```
sys.stdout = ?
print "hopefully this is in an output cell now"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python) The second answer is much better than the accepted one, as it ensures proper cleanup and avoids having to write a bunch of manual code.

Answer (score 4):

Use a temporary variable:

```
stdout_backup = sys.stdout
```

Sending its output to a file:

```
sys.stdout = open(filename, 'w')
print "stuff"
```

Sending its output back to the output cells:

```
sys.stdout = stdout_backup
print "this is in an output cell now"
```